# How to apply random forest properly?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am new to machine learning and python. Now I am trying to apply random forest to predict binary results of a target. In my data I have 24 predictors (1000 observations) where one of them is categorical(gender) and all the others numerical. Among numerical ones, there are two types of values which are volume of money in euros (very skewed and scaled) and numbers (number of transactions from an atm). I have transformed the big scale features and did the imputation. Last, I have checked correlation and collinearity and based on that removed some features (as a result I had 24 features.) Now when I implement RF it is always perfect in the training set while the ratios not so good according to crossvalidation. And even applying it in the test set it gives very very low recall values. How should I remedy this?

```
def classification_model(model, data, predictors, outcome):
    # Fit the model:
    model.fit(data[predictors], data[outcome])

    # Make predictions on training set:
    predictions = model.predict(data[predictors])

    # Print accuracy
    accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(predictions, data[outcome])
    print("Accuracy : %s" % "{0:.3%}".format(accuracy))

    # Perform k-fold cross-validation with 5 folds
    kf = KFold(data.shape[0], n_folds=5)
    error = []
    for train, test in kf:
        # Filter training data
        train_predictors = (data[predictors].iloc[train, :])

        # The target we're using to train the algorithm.
        train_target = data[outcome].iloc[train]

        # Training the algorithm using the predictors and target.
        model.fit(train_predictors, train_target)

        # Record error from each cross-validation run
        error.append(model.score(data[predictors].iloc[test, :], data[outcome].iloc[test]))

    print("Cross-Validation Score : %s" % "{0:.3%}".format(np.mean(error)))

    # Fit the model again so that it can be refered outside the function:
    model.fit(data[predictors], data[outcome])



outcome_var = 'Sold'
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=20)
predictor_var = train.drop('Sold', axis=1).columns.values
classification_model(model,train,predictor_var,outcome_var)

#Create a series with feature importances:
featimp = pd.Series(model.feature_importances_, index=predictor_var).sort_values(ascending=False)
print(featimp)

outcome_var = 'Sold'
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=20, max_depth=20, oob_score = True)
predictor_var = ['fet1','fet2','fet3','fet4']
classification_model(model,train,predictor_var,outcome_var)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Random Forest it is very easy to overfit. To resolve this you need to do parameter search a little more rigorously to know the best parameter to use. [Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/randomized_search.html
) is the link on how to do this: (from the scikit doc).

It is overfitting and you need to search for the best parameter that will work work on the model. The link provides implementation for Grid and Randomized search for hyper parameter estimation.
And it will also be fun to go through this MIT Artificial Intelligence lecture to get get deep theoretical orientation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHBmv7qCey4&t=318s.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the post and the links. Indeed, I have tried GridSearchCV and observed relatively better results when the best parameters were used. My main problem was especially recall values. Even it improved well. But eventually still it overfits.I will keep searching.

Comment: Did you try Randomised search!

Comment: I did not know until you mentioned! I will take a look.